# System Call in Python via MINGW32 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, wget, system-calls, mingw32

I am trying to figure out a way to call wget from my python script on a windows machine.  I have wget installed under /bin on the machine.  Making a call using the subprocess or os modules seems to raise errors no matter what I try.  I'm assuming this is related to the fact that I need to route my python system call through minGW so that wget is recognized.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you can run it in cmd.exe first. You can use full path to wget or append your /bin to environment variable PATH.

Comment: Show us the code you tried. If you're using `shell=True`, have you tried not using that? Or setting the `COMSPEC` environment variable to a MinGW shell instead of the default `cmd.exe`?

Comment: When I do 'echo $PATH' in mingw I get that /bin is in the environment path.  I get that mingw recognizes 'wget' but command prompt in windows doesn't.  Therefore, my python doesn't as well.  I tried adding \bin to the windows path variable but it didn't seem to work.   I used 'setx path "%path%;\bin"'.  The changes show up in the path but command prompt still doesn't recognize 'wget' or 'wget.exe'.  Also, in general I can't seem to navigate to \bin through command prompt where as in mingw I can.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I can do a 'call("cmd.exe")' from python and command prompt opens up.  When I do a 'call("cmd.exe",shell=True)' from python I get that something runs in IDLE for a minute and then nothing with no command prompt showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as under "MinGW". You probably mean under MSYS, a Unix emulation environment for Windows. MSYS makes things look like Unix, but you're still running everything under Windows. In particular MSYS maps `/bin` to the drive and directory where you install MSYS. If you installed MSYS to `C:\MSYS` then your MSYS `/bin` directory is really `C:\MSYS\bin`.

When you add `/bin` to your MSYS `PATH` environment variable, MSYS searches the directory `C:\MSYS\bin`. When you add `/bin` to the Windows `PATH` environment using the command `SETX`, Windows will look in the `\bin` directory of the current drive.

Presumably your version of Python is the standard Windows port of Python. Since it's a normal Windows application, it doesn't interpret the `PATH` environment variable the way you're expecting it to. With `/bin` in the path, it will search the `\bin` directory of the current drive. Since `wget` is in `C:\MSYS\bin` not `\bin` of the current directory you an error when trying to run it from Python.

Note that if you run a Windows command from the MSYS shell, MSYS will automatically convert its `PATH` to a Windows compatible format, changing MSYS pathnames into Windows pathnames. This means you should be able to get your Python script to work by running Python from the MSYS shell.

Comment: So true.  Before you had posted this I realized the path issue and decided to quickly throw a copy of wget.exe under C:\Windows.  It's recognized now when running python.  That's a nice note about msys running python...I'll have to try it out...once my path variable isn't so horrendous. Thanks